# elasticsearch - field filterable but not searchable

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Using elastic 2.3.5. Is there a way to make a field filterable, but not searchable?  For example, I have a `language` field, with values like `en-US`.  Setting several filters in `query->bool->filter->term`, I'm able to filter the result set without affecting the score, for example, searching for only documents that have `en-US` in the `language` field.

However, I want a query searching for the term `en-US` to return no results, since this is not really an indexed field for searching, but just so I can filter.

Can I do this?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Are you asking if there is a way to control a list of allowed fields in the `query_string` query?

Comment: If that field is `"index": "no"` and you want to filter on it (`"term": {"not_indexed_field": {"value": "en-US"}}` it will be like filtering against a list of no terms. So, it will always **not match**.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and sorry I did not respond sooner.  Upvoting them for your willingness to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ElasticSearch use an _all field to allow fast full-text search on entire documents. This is why searching for en-US in all fields of all documents return you the one containing 'language':'en-US'. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html

You can specify `"include_in_all": false` in the mapping to deactivate include of a field into _all.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "title": { 
          "type": "string"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "language": { 
          "type": "string",
          "include_in_all": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, searching for 'US' in all field will return only document containing US in title or country. But you still be able to filter your query using the language field.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/include-in-all.html

Comment: I upvoted and marked as accepted but meant to also leave a comment saying thanks for taking the time to answer -- it was exactly what I was looking for.