# Elasticsearch filterable index but not searchable

Tags: elasticsearch

What it says on the tin. I am trying to make a field that is filterable, but not searchable. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980506/elasticsearch-field-filterable-but-not-searchable) has an answer, but the `_all` field is being deprecated in Elasticsearch 6.0, and we are getting deprecation warnings on import if we have `include_in_all => false` on the specific index. We don't want to be locked to Elasticsearch 5.x, so is there a way to achieve this going forward?

Whitelisting fields would be very awkward, as we have a large number of indexes to search over, and only want to exclude the single filterable field.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you want to apply filter , the field should be index. all the indexed fields are searchable. you can change your query to avoid searching the desired  field.

Comment: I am trying to, but I'd rather *exclude* the single field, than have to *include* the dozens that I do want to search. If it isn't possible, well, that's unfortunate, but am hoping there's an easier way.